# Error in validObject(.Object) : invalid class “mpfr” object: Not all components are of class 'mpfr1'

Tags: r, mpfr

I am getting

> Error in validObject(.Object) :
> invalid class “mpfr” object: Not all components are of class 'mpfr1'

when running the below code.

```
for (i in 1:length(stocksRetData)){
  
  betaVal = mpfr(cov(RM,stocksRetData[[i]]$Ret)/var(RM),400)
  Ri = mpfr(mean(stocksRetData[[i]]$Ret),400)
  RMM <- mpfr(mean(RM),400)
  
  CALCData <- rbind(CALCData,
                
        data.frame(
          StockName = stocksRetData[[i]]$Name[1],
          AriMean = Ri,
          Beta = betaVal,
          Alpha =  Ri - (RMM*betaVal),
          Variance = mpfr(var(stocksRetData[[i]]$Ret),400),
          StdDev =mpfr(StdDev(stocksRetData[[i]]$Ret),400),
          SysRisk = mpfr(StdDev(RM),400) * betaVal,
          UnSysRisk = mpfr(StdDev(stocksRetData[[i]]$Ret),400) - (mpfr(StdDev(RM),400) * betaVal)
        )
                    
  )
  
}
```

When i checked by stepping in the code then all the lines were returning mpfr class except these which I guess is causing the issue but not sure about it.

```
> Ri - (RMM*betaVal)
1 'mpfr' number of precision  400   bits 
[1] 0.625840790501628493045834213614270386838227067753351556987835048462276432701401063241064548492431640625
> mpfr(var(stocksRetData[[i]]$Ret),400)
1 'mpfr' number of precision  400   bits 
[1] 67.4595123849608313548742444254457950592041015625
> mpfr(StdDev(stocksRetData[[i]]$Ret),400)
'mpfrMatrix' of dim(.) =  (1, 1) of precision  400   bits 
       [,1]                                                                                                                       
StdDev 8.2133739951959352509902601013891398906707763671875000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> mpfr(StdDev(RM),400) * betaVal
'mpfrMatrix' of dim(.) =  (1, 1) of precision  400   bits 
       [,1]                                                                                                                       
StdDev 5.3785327104693395091702376050795513975148703141811485443891070745703331112963496707379817962646484375000000000000000000000
> mpfr(StdDev(stocksRetData[[i]]$Ret),400) - (mpfr(StdDev(RM),400) * betaVal)
'mpfrMatrix' of dim(.) =  (1, 1) of precision  400   bits 
       [,1]                                                                                                                       
StdDev 2.8348412847265957418200224963095884931559060530063514556108929254296668887036503292620182037353515625000000000000000000000
```

Comment: How was `CALCData` initialized?

Comment: `CALCData <- data.frame(
  StockName = as.character(),
  AriMean = as.numeric(),
  Beta = as.numeric(),
  Alpha = as.numeric(),
  Variance = as.numeric(),
  StdDev = as.numeric(),
  SysRisk = as.numeric(),
  UnSysRisk = as.numeric(),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)`

Comment: Except for `StockName` all other columns are initialized as beeing of class `"numeric"`, not `"mpfr"`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I can't do as.mpfr()

Answer (score 0):

Try the following `lapply` loop. Untested, since we don't have `stocksRetData`.

```
library(Rmpfr)

# Use a constant only once
precBits <- 400
RMM <- mpfr(mean(RM),precBits)

# These values remain constant in the loop    
MeanRM <- mean(RM)
VarRM <- var(RM)
StdDev <- sd
StdDevRM <- StdDev(RM)
mpfrStdDevRM <- mpfr(StdDev(RM), precBits)

# the loop returns a list of lists
CALCData <- lapply(seq_along(stocksRetData), function(i){
  betaVal <- mpfr(cov(RM,stocksRetData[[i]]$Ret)/VarRM, precBits)
  Ri <- mpfr(mean(stocksRetData[[i]]$Ret), precBits)
  Name <- stocksRetData[[i]]$Name[1]
  Variance <- mpfr(var(stocksRetData[[i]]$Ret), precBits)
  StdDevRet <- mpfr(StdDev(stocksRetData[[i]]$Ret), precBits)
  res <- list(
    StockName = Name,
    AriMean = Ri,
    Beta = betaVal,
    Alpha =  Ri - RMM*betaVal,
    Variance = Variance,
    StdDev = StdDevRet,
    SysRisk = mpfrStdDevRM * betaVal,
    UnSysRisk = StdDevRet - mpfrStdDevRM * betaVal
  )
  res
})

tmp <- lapply(CALCData, function(x) do.call(cbind, x))
CALCData <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, tmp))
rm(tmp)

CALCData
```

---

### Test data

```
set.seed(2021)
n <- 10
stocksRetData <- data.frame(Name = LETTERS[1:n], Ret = rnorm(n))
stocksRetData <- replicate(3, stocksRetData, simplify = FALSE)
RM <- rnorm(n)
```

Comment: StocksRetData is just random stock names and numbers

Comment: @Stupid_Intern And `RM`? Is it just a vector?

Comment: Yes its just a vector

Comment: This `stocksRetData[[i]]$Name` doesn't make any sense: `stocksRetData[[i]]` is the **i-th** column of the data.frame `stocksRetData`. When indexing, you probably want `stocksRetData$Name[i]`, the `ith` name in the column, and `stocksRetData$Ret[i]`. But then the variance of a constant is zero.

Comment: stocksRetData is a list of dataframes

Comment: @Stupid_Intern That's important information that should be in the question. See now, with me it runs without errors.